# Checking a word in a file to do a statement by Shell

Tags: shell, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have this file:

```
wwsex gender wwmm mother 
mm ccmother ccfather
```

And I need to check if a file contains a specific word (exactly the same, identic) to do the  statement considering just the second line. I tried this:

```
if grep -q ww 'my.file'; then
echo "correct - just a simple example" >> file
fi
```

But it's wrong, this way I checked all the file and consider the `wwsex` and `wwmm` to do the statement. But I need to be specific in the word and the line.

Comment: Did you do any google research?

Comment: I did, and I found the command above. It was the closest I found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an option to `grep` that let's you select only lines containing matches that form full words: `-w` or `--word-regex`, see [man grep](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html).

```
if grep -wq ww 'my.file'; then
```